# Facebook Login after declined Permission

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, fbsdk

Since the release of the new FBSDK I'm facing this problem.

**Scenario**:

1.User logs into my app via FBLogin
2.User **declines** one of my permissions

3. My app sets him back to first screen (I don't allow creating an account without providing info)
4. He tries logging in again
5. He realizes FBSDK saved his settings he cannot change.

How do I provide the user with the possibility to change it?
My app runs to the point, I am noticing a declined permission and I give my user a notification to change the setting.
But I am clueless what to do at this point.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, you must not make all permissions as mandatory from Facebook.
Although if needed be, then you can check for the permission granted or not using the following code

```
if ([[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken] hasGranted:@"publish_actions"]) {
  // TODO: publish content.
} else {
  FBSDKLoginManager *loginManager = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
  [loginManager logInWithPublishPermissions:@[@"publish_actions"]
                         fromViewController:self
                                    handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
    //TODO: process error or result.
  }];
}
```

To check for Declined Permissions

```
  FBSDKLoginManager *loginManager = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
  [loginManager logInWithPublishPermissions:@[@"publish_actions"]
                         fromViewController:self
                                    handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
   if ([result.declinedPermissions containsObject:@”publish_actions”]) {
     // TODO: do not request permissions again immediately. Consider providing a NUX 
    // describing  why the app want this permission.
   } else {
   // ...
   }
  }];
```

**Note** : If the user declines permissions, you should not immediately ask for them again. Instead your app should continue functioning. You may consider providing a guide or user interface explaining the benefits of granting that permission but should only ask for it again if the user performs an action that needs it.

Ref : 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/permissions
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/errors

Comment: These are actually the steps I have done until now. my problem is to handle the 'process error' (your first else). Is there a way to force the user to provide the info? If so: How do I program resetting the login?